# Mootools add a class to 'a' href="something"

Tags: javascript, class, mootools

The situation is that I want to add a class 'display-none' to li eliment which has a child eliment 'a'

```
<li class="mostread">
    <a href="/intranet/Admin/Error-Pages/404.html" class="mostread">404</a>
</li>
```

i.e.,
if li class mostread has child element a href="/intranet/Admin/Error-Pages/404.html" and class mostread then add class 'display-none' to the parent li.

After processing it would look like

```
<li class="mostread display-none">
    <a href="/intranet/Admin/Error-Pages/404.html" class="mostread">404</a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$$('li a.mostread').each(function(el){
    if ('/intranet/Admin/Error-Pages/404.html' === el.get('href') &&
        'li' === el.getParent().get('tag')) {

        el.addClass('display-none');
    }
});
```

Note that this is using **mootools 1.2**